# C++ lambda within a function of namespace?

Tags: c++, lambda

I am debating between the following two styles of using lambda:

a) declare the lambda in namespace in a `.cc` file.

b) declare the lambda in a function.

I am leaning towards a), because it makes the `func()` less verbose,
and no functor gets created every time the function gets called. Are there any disadvantage/negative effects that a) might have?

Style a)

```
namespace XXX{

auto lambda_in_namespace=...; // this is a cc file, lambda will not export 

void func(){
   // use lambda_in_namespace
}

}
```

Style b)

```
namespace XXX{

void func(){
   auto scoped_lambda = ...
   // use scoped_lambda 
}

}
```

Comment: If you are not declaring it inline where you need it, why not just use a plain function or functor?

Comment: Will the lambda ever be used in other functions, or only in `func`? The general recommendation is to declare or define variables (which will include things like lambdas) as close to their use as possible, including in the closest scope possible.

Comment: If your lambda doesn't capture, there will be no "functor created" every time `func` is called since the lambda is convertible to a plain function. The compiler is smart enough to optimize that.

Comment: intention is because lambda supports auto on input and output types, it reduce the verbosity.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot for the suggestions on general practice, @Someprogrammerdude  and it is good to know compiler will probably just inline the operator() if there is no capture. @ super

Comment: @iamxuxiao so does a plain template function (reduce verbosity that is) - which is what a generic lambda basically *is*.

Comment: agree, and good point. although using template function , is slightly less compact than using a lambda, because of the keywords.  Now I conclude a) does not bring too much benefit. I should just use a scoped lambda.

Comment: without more details imho this is opinion-based

Answer (score 0):

The main motivation for lambda functions was to use in function calls where a function-like object(s) was expected. The standard heaader `<std::algorithm>` has many such functions.

As a design principle, (b) in your posted code is better than (a). It keeps the lambda local to the function where it gets used and doesn't pollute the `namespace` that contains `func`.

As a matter of practice, (b) could be a performance bottleneck if `func` gets called millions of times. With modern day machines, I seriously doubt you will notice the difference even for thousands of invocations of `func`.

My suggestion:

1. Time the two approaches with 1,000s of calls, then 1,000,000s of calls.
2. If the performance difference is not noticeable, stick to (b).
3. If the performance difference is noticeable, use (a). However, with this approach, I would suggest useing a regular function instead of a lambda. Please note that a lambda contains two parts -- an object and some executable code. A function contains just executable code.